# VNC server failure after booting - Failed to get connection to session

Tags: vnc, gconf

I'm having this error from the log file of a Tiger VNC server (version tigervnc-server-1.1.0-5.el6_4.1.x86_64):

```
Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-Auq6xEVNZb: Connection refused)

(Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-Auq6xEVNZb: Connection refused)GConf warning: failure listing pairs in `/apps/nautilus/desktop-metadata': Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-Auq6xEVNZb: Connection refused)
```

When I reboot the server, it works nice, but after a while it start failing and when I connect there's no desktop and there's a pop-up windows appearing and disappearing.

I've recently have deleted by mistake /tmp directory, could that be the source of the problem?  How could this be solved?

This problem is also causing problems with disk usage because this log file is always growing, which seems to be related with a persistent error state.

Thanks!

Comment: When writing questions, use "<pre>" to distinguish things like error text. Indentation and the ` charcter are used to designate code. 

Its also not clear which VNC server you are talking about. Perhaps type out the full name or provide a link to the software you are using.

Lastly, avoid content that is not relevent. For example, in this case, the fact that the log file is getting too large sounds like an effect of the problem, but not really related to its cause. What is your reason for its inclusion here?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by creating a directory /tmp/dbus-Auq6xEVNZb (it varies on each server, you need to check the error and see the path VNC server is trying to access). The command for that is:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/dbus-Auq6xEVNZb
```

It seems that another solution could be to modify ~/.dbus directory ownership (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gconf/+bug/367169).

**EDIT**: After rebooting, this solution NO LONGER WORKS. I also tried to delete the content of /tmp/ (NOT THE DIRECTORY ITSELF) and change ownership to dbus user, but it doesn't work neither.

**EDIT 2**: Reinstalling dbus has worked. I'm no longer having those errors.

Comment: try reinstalling dbus. so that during uninstall / reinstall it cycles through permissions without you manually having to guess them.

Comment: @Fred Concklin Yes! Reinstalling dbus seems to work fine!